# My Laravel Project .htaccess getting 403 error

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I installing a Laravel application in my Namecheap server. I'm getting a 403 Error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure it has to do with your htaccess? Are all the folders in the correct place? If you're running on a shared hosy (usually with a public_html folder) you need to deploy and change some paths in your index.php,

Comment: maybe rewrite module not enable in server

Comment: The `.htaccess` code you posted is not complete - there's nothing that rewrites arbitrary requests to the front-controller. You should probably have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory. But as Christoffer mention above, what does this have to do with `.htaccess` anyway?